# How do I add a new node to the end of an existing XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

How do I add a new node to the end of an existing XML file?

I understand how, but how in the end?

For example, I have the following XML file and need to add a new node "entry" to the end of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <entries>
- <entry type="debit">
<amount>100</amount> 
<date>11.11.2010</date> 
- <description>
- <![CDATA[ Описание записи]]> 
</description>
<category>Продукты</category> 
</entry>
- <entry type="credit">
<amount>50</amount> 
<date>11.11.2010</date> 
- <description>
- <![CDATA[ Описание записи]]> 
</description>
<category>Продукты</category> 
</entry>
- <entry type="debit">
<amount>100</amount> 
<date>11.11.2010</date> 
- <description>
- <![CDATA[ Описание записи]]> 
</description>
<category>Продукты</category> 
</entry>
</entries>
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please provide examples of XML before and after the addition.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849043/fastest-way-to-add-new-node-to-end-of-an-xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, is there a way to add an XML node to a file on disk WITHOUT loading it first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773564/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-add-an-xml-node-to-a-file-on-disk-without-loading-it-fir)

Comment: About 10 close matches for the title in the Related list.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to load the XML into memory, append the child node, then write out the whole document again. For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("before.xml");
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("extra"));
doc.Save("after.xml");
```

If that isn't exactly what you were after, please clarify your question.

Comment: thanks for unswer, but how add in existing file without create new file. use only system.xml, not linq.

Comment: @Dimitri: Same principle - load it, change in memory, save it. Just use `XmlDocument` instead of `XDocument`. If you don't want to create a *new* file, just overwrite the old one. If you've tried all of that and had problems, please edit your question to show *what* you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("before.xml");
//XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//Create a new node.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("entry");
elem.InnerText="";
//Add the node to the document.
//root.AppendChild(elem);

//Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML...");

doc.LastChild.AppendChild(elem);

doc.Save("before.xml");'
```